# Can use snmpset to modify the configuration of Cisco Router if SNMP RO?

Tags: snmp, cisco, nms

We'd like to modify the configuration via SNMPset command but unfortunately now the SNMPv3 was wrongly configured to Read-only.  So, we can't add the cmd to cisco router now unless we are using console directly.

Any experts here could advise?

Also, May I ask the snmpset for v3 cmd is correct?

```
snmpset -v3 -l authPriv -u <SNMPv3 USER> -a MD5 -A <PASSWORD> <SWITCH_IP> .1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.96.1.1.1.1.14.222 integer 6
```

In the past, we could modify the config via SNMPv2.

```
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.9.9.96.1.1.1.1.2.222 = INTEGER: 1
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.9.9.96.1.1.1.1.3.222 = INTEGER: 1
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.9.9.96.1.1.1.1.4.222 = INTEGER: 4
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.9.9.96.1.1.1.1.5.222 = IpAddress: 172.16.1.1
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.9.9.96.1.1.1.1.6.222 = STRING: "switch.config"
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.9.9.96.1.1.1.1.14.222 = INTEGER: 1
```

Comment: Network device management belongs to ServerFault.com. Besides, if the device administrators configured the device to be read-only for SNMP v3 commands, you shouldn't expect any command can hack the device. If going to use the console is the only way, then do it before it's too late.

Comment: you are requesting `authPriv`, but you didn't provide any privacy parameters (algorithm and secret)

Answer (score 1):

If the config error is not in the startup config, power cycle.  Or use telnet/ssh/etc if that is available.  Either way, you need legitimate access of course.